# iOS5 Facebook sometimes does not return to my app after authentication

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, cordova

I'm using Cordova/PhoneGap2.2 with the https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin to handle authentication for my app. I've tested it and it is able to provide all the different authentication options (via Facebook App / Site / Dialogue etc.), but have seen one issue with the Facebook app authenticaiton on an iOS5 iphone where occasionally my app switches to the Facebook app to authenticate, but the Facebook app seems to ignore my authentication request and just displays its newsfeed instead of returning control back to my app.

This is a pretty rare issue which is difficult to replicate and I've only seen it happen on an iOS5 iphone4s (with the latest Facebook app installed). On one occasion when I was able to reproduce the problem I debugged through the app and checked the returned accessToken, which was not expired, so it doesn't seem like it would be caused by an expired session, and even if so, I would expect the Facebook app to give some message about it rather than just ignoring the authentication request and displaying its news feed. Any ideas on what could cause this? It's clearly not a problem with my app's URL scheme since the Facebook app is able to return to my app in almost all other cases without any problems.

Comment: I am seeing the same, have for a week or few, and it is nowhere near as "rare" as I'd like it to be. :-(

Comment: same is happening for me, any updates on this?